# Java Swing Boxlayout: having panels of different sizes (ratio to each other)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, windowbuilder, boxlayout

I'm trying to create a boxlayout panel with 2 other panels inside it, one of which is only half the size of the other (so a ratio of 1/3 to 2/3). Setting preferred size doesn't seem to work and I've been unable to figure out any other way (the following code was mainly generated with Windowbuilder, so apologies if it's a bit of a mess):

```
public class GUIControls extends JFrame implements IGUIControls {
    private JTextField textField;

    private int posX=0,posY=0;

    public GUIControls() {

        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel rootPanel = new JPanel();
        rootPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 255), 1, true));
        rootPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        getContentPane().add(rootPanel, "name_25253210045969");
        rootPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(rootPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        rootPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));

        JPanel menuLeft = new JPanel();
        rootPanel.add(menuLeft);
        menuLeft.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        menuLeft.setLayout(null);
        menuLeft.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((1/3)*rootPanel.getWidth(), rootPanel.getHeight()));

        JPanel contentRight = new JPanel();
        rootPanel.add(contentRight);
        contentRight.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentRight.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((2/3)*rootPanel.getWidth(), rootPanel.getHeight()));
        contentRight.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
                CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) getContentPane().getLayout();
                cardLayout.show(getContentPane(), "name_36737116256884");
            }
        });
        contentRight.setLayout(null);

        setUndecorated(true);   

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
           public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
           {
              posX=e.getX();
              posY=e.getY();
           }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
             public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt)
             {
                //sets frame position when mouse dragged            
                setLocation (evt.getXOnScreen()-posX,evt.getYOnScreen()-posY);

             }
        });

    }

    public void runGUI(){
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                GUIControls guiControls = new GUIControls();
                guiControls.pack();
                guiControls.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                guiControls.setSize(600, 400);
                guiControls.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I'd go about doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: `Setting preferred size doesn't seem to work` - sounds like a reasonable solution to me. Post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem when you use this approach.

Comment: I've added in what I attempted to do, still no luck though.

Comment: That is NOT a `SSCCE`, so I can't help.

Comment: Right, well, okay. I wasn't really sure what the code was that was relevant so I've added the rest in, there's not that much but that is everything that could possibly be causing this (the opposite of a SSCCE I guess, but I'm not really sure how to cut this down without knowing where the problem is).

Comment: `I guess, but I'm not really sure how to cut this down without knowing where the problem is)` - You post the minimal amount of code required to demonstrate the problem. How are the KeyListener or MouseListener's relevant to the problem? You have a layout problem. So you need a panel with a BoxLayout. Then you have two child panels added to it. And you have a frame. Don't complicate the issue. The point of a SSCCE is to simplify the problem. Anyway you have made an effort so see the edit to my answer.

Comment: `I guess, but I'm not really sure how to cut this down without knowing where the problem is)` - and actually the approach should be the reverse, don't cut down but start fresh. That is create a frame with with two panels. If you have the same problem, then you have a SSCCE to post. If the panel goes away then you know the problem is with your current code and you can compare code to see what the difference is. Or you start adding in more code to the one that is working until it stops working. Then you know what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the `GridBagLayout`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/) for more information. I would guess you would need to play with the `weightx` property.

Or you could use the [Relative Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/) which was specifically designed to do this.

Edit:

Did you do any debugging? What happens when you add:

```
System.out.println(menuLeft.getPreferredSize());
System.out.println(contentRight.getPreferredSize());
```

You have two problems:

1. What is the value of 1/3? You need to fix your size calculation.
2. What is the size of your rootPanel? A component doesn't have a size until the component is displayed on the visible GUI. You set the preferred size of the component.

Comment: Okay, so I fixed the problem by hard coding in the width rather than using getWidth() (which may cause problems when I'm trying to make window resizing work, but eh). Thanks a lot for the help.